# Are CTEs multithreaded?

Tags: postgresql, cte, parallelism

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228058) and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query_Execution) seem to suggest that they are, but I've also been told (source unlocatable) that a multi-row single-statement insert will only use one thread for all writing, that to multithread it, the query should be broken up and sent to as many connections as there are cores.

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) states that CTEs are executed "concurrently", but none linked say explicitly in effect that "CTEs will use all available cores to process any parallel sub-statements and/or the main query".

Do CTEs always use all available cores for any parallel tasks?  If so, are there any caveats aside from what could be reasonably assumed from chaining with `RETURNING`?

Comment: Postgres does not run any statement multithreaded. That includes CTEs The "concurrently" is probably only there to indicated that there is no inherent order how they are processed

Comment: Multithreaded processing is something you do NOT want in the database(under normal circumstances). Databases goal is to protect data and also to provide reasonable resource sharing. Multithreaded processing would give all the servers resources to a single user, which is something you usually you do not want to happen.

Comment: @ibre5041 What if there's only one core?

Comment: Even then you have same CPU time and some disk IOs to be split up among multiple users. If you spend it to perform a single statement then other users will have to wait.

Comment: @ibre5041 Huh? There's nothing at all wrong with careful and appropriate use of threading if it can be used to parallelise CPU-heavy portions of queries across multiple cores or to help with I/O wait concurrency in a blocking I/O model. PostgreSQL doesn't support any kind of concurrency within a single session/query, but it'd be nice if it did, as not everyone's workload is pure OLTP (large numbers of fairly simple selects and DML).

Comment: @Craig Ringer at least in Oracle the parallel processing is something that must be explicitly allowed. The database will never process any statement in parallel by it's own. As this could block the whole OTLP system. This is also the reason why DBAs are cautious when they see parallel hint anywhere.

Comment: @ibre5041: Parallel processing costs extra money in Oracle - that is why you have to be sceptical when you see it. It is "free" in SQL Server and is a great feature when used properly (it is not a replacement for good indexes). Postgres is a bit 1980'ies - which is why they don't have parallelism built into the engine. Note that most Postgres variants like Redshift add parallelism to the engine to make it suck less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres currently does not use parallelism when executing a single query. The entire execution engine is single threaded for each query (you can of course still execute multiple queries in parallel). This lack of "intra query parallelism" is one of the great drawbacks of running Postgres or MySQL. Basically, it makes those engines unfit for purpose on large datasets.

To get multi-threaded Postgres execution, you either need to split up the query into multiple queries yourself or run a Postgres compatible variant like Amazon Redshift or Greenplum (the former has added intra query parallelism to the code base, the latter does the splitting for you).

Whenever you feel the need to run a parallel query, first ask yourself: Could I add indexes that would make this fast enough without parallelism? If that answer is "Yes", pursue that option first. Very often though, you need brute force. And when it comes to brute force, vanilla Postgres is unfortunately not a particularly good database engine.

Comment: This is no longer accurate as of PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: How so? The "parallelism" added there is so weak it still does not hold a candle to a fully parallel engine.

Comment: How _good_ it may or may not be doesn't change the fact that the answer is now factually incorrect.

Comment: The entire engine isn't multi threaded yet. Only the operators that have been explicitly made parallel. So I think its neither correct nor incorrect at this point