# Are mutliple client-based queries multithreaded internally in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, parallelism

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86685/241198) seems to suggest, that if i connect to the same instance of Postgres running on my machine, multiple connections from clients are handled in parallel. Is that true?

Can I start 4 shells running psql and have their queries be handled in parrallel?

Comment: Yes. That's the whole point of a database server

Comment: Can all connections come from the same machine? ODer does this lead to issues? So six shells to the same local host is not an issue?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. The worker threads don’t care where the connection comes from. Processes will contend with each other for resources, but it’s the same situation for any other service. It’s why we have multiprocessing operating systems.